# As I am new to nodejs, I am Unable to create file in tmp location of aws lambda using nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel, aws-lambda

Error:"errorMessage": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/excel.xlsx'"
Below is the code snippet. Can anyone please assist on this.
NOTE: I tried in python and it is working as expected but in nodejs it's not working.

```
// Require library
    var excel = require('excel4node');

// Create a new instance of a Workbook class
    var workbook = new excel.Workbook();

// Add Worksheets to the workbook
   var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
   var worksheet2 = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 2');

// Create a reusable style
   var style = workbook.createStyle({
  font: {
    color: '#FF0800',
    size: 12
  },
  numberFormat: '$#,##0.00; ($#,##0.00); -'
});

// Set value of cell A1 to 100 as a number type styled with paramaters of style
   worksheet.cell(1,1).number(100).style(style);

// Set value of cell B1 to 300 as a number type styled with paramaters of style
   worksheet.cell(1,2).number(200).style(style);

// Set value of cell C1 to a formula styled with paramaters of style
   worksheet.cell(1,3).formula('A1 + B1').style(style);

// Set value of cell A2 to 'string' styled with paramaters of style
   worksheet.cell(2,1).string('string').style(style);

// Set value of cell A3 to true as a boolean type styled with paramaters of style but with an adjustment to the font size.
   worksheet.cell(3,1).bool(true).style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});

   workbook.write('/tmp/excel.xlsx');


   var XLSX = require('xlsx')
   var workbook = XLSX.readFile('/tmp/excel.xlsx');enter code here
   var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
   var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
   console.log(xlData);
```

Answer (score 1):

`workbook.write('/tmp/excel.xlsx');`

This is an asynchronous function, and takes a callback function as a 2nd parameter.

If you want to act on this file after  it writes, you must put your other logic in the callback function.  e.g.

```
workbook.write('/tmp/excel.xlsx', function(err, stats) => {
  // err would be the error from the interior fs.writeFile
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you response..I replaced the code as below
workbook.write('/tmp/excel.xlsx',function(err, data){
  // err would be the error from the interior fs.writeFile
  if(err){console.log(err)}
  else{
    var workbook = XLSX.readFile('/tmp/excel.xlsx');
    var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
    var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
    console.log(xlData);
  }
});

Comment: but it is not displaying any thing..the output is blank not even error.